# how disable 'attempting to receive mail from folder' spring integration mail in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

i need to disable "attempting to receive mail from folder " log in spring integration.

Because it writes a lot of logs in catalina.out Tomcat and increases the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See more info in the issue you have raised: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3430.

This is not an `INFO` starting with Spring Integration version `5.4`.

As a workaround you can just disable logging for the `AbstractMailReceiver` class making it on the, let's say, `WARN` level.

According your tags in the question, you probably use Spring Boot, so its configuration property for the logging may look like this:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver=warn
```

and you won't see that `INFO` message in logs any more.

Comment: sorry I did not understand what to do.
I use a log4j and spring boot.

Comment: So, add that `logging.level` entry into your `application.properties`. See more info in Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/howto.html#howto-logging